# How can I dismiss opened subview?

Tags: ios, swift

There is one view controller with a button in the main storyboard. And there is one Swift file (Helper.swift).

ViewController.swift file:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func openView(_ sender: UIButton) {
        pop_Up_A_View()
    }
}
```

Helper.swift file:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

func pop_Up_A_View()
{
    let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!
    let v = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: window.frame.origin.x, y: window.frame.origin.y, width: window.frame.width, height: window.frame.height))
    window.addSubview(v);
    v.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.7)

    let indicatorTemp = UIActivityIndicatorView (frame: CGRect(x: window.frame.origin.x, y: window.frame.origin.y, width: window.frame.width, height: window.frame.height))
    indicatorTemp.startAnimating()
    indicatorTemp.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.white
    window.addSubview(indicatorTemp)
}
```

As you can see, I see view with an activity indicator by calling `pop_Up_A_View` function. How can I dismiss this view with the activity indicator? I tried to write this code as a `close_Sub_View` function but I could not figure out.

Actually, one more case I should implement. If there is an opened subview already and then `pop_Up_A_View` function should not open one more.

Comment: what is the timing of removing the animation? or what user events will trigger the removal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give your view tag to identification and to be removed. also you have to add your indicator view inside the view v instead of window directly

Use following

```
func pop_Up_A_View(){

    let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!
    if let view = window.viewWithTag(1000) as? UIView {
        return
    }

    let v = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: window.frame.origin.x, y: window.frame.origin.y, width: window.frame.width, height: window.frame.height))
    v.tag = 1000
    v.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.7)

    let indicatorTemp = UIActivityIndicatorView (frame: CGRect(x: window.frame.origin.x, y: window.frame.origin.y, width: window.frame.width, height: window.frame.height))
    indicatorTemp.startAnimating()
    indicatorTemp.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.white
    v.addSubview(indicatorTemp)
    window.addSubview(v);
}

func close()
{
    let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!
    if let view = window.viewWithTag(1000) {
        (view as! UIView).removeFromSuperview()
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. Question: When i call close function does any code go under process in ViewController.swift file like viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear ? (I have checked these two with print function. They are not called. But any other ? ) @Ajaysaini

Comment: none of view controllers lifecycle methods are called when you close the  indicator.